# How to convert this recursive function to a dp based solution?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, implementation

This is the recursive function

```
def integerPartition(m, n):
    if(n==0):
        return 0
    if(m ==0):
        return 1
    if(m<0):
        return 0

    return integerPartition(m,n-1) + integerPartition(m-n,n)
```

and this is what i have done in c++

```
        // n -> no. of persons
        // m -> amount of money to be distributed
        // dp table of order (n+1)*(m+1) 
        long long int dp[n+1][m+1] ;
        //initializing values to 0
        for(i = 0; i<=n ; i++)
            for(j = 0; j<= m ; j++)
                dp[i][j] = 0;

        Print(n,m,dp);
        cout << "\n";
        //Case 1 - if there is no persons i.e n = 0 answer will be 0
        //Case 2 - if there is no money i.e. m = 0 there is only 1 way answer will be 1
        for ( i = 1; i<= n ; i++ )
            dp[i][0] = 1;
            dp[i][i] = 1;

        Print(n,m,dp);

        for ( i = 1; i<= n ; i++){
            for ( j = 1; j<= m ; j++){
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] ;

                if(i>=j){
                    dp[i][j] += dp[i-j][j];
                }
                // else if(i==j){
                //     dp[i][j] += 1;
                // }
            }
    }
```

but the answers i am getting are not matching with the recursive one i don't understand what am i missing if anyone can please help me to correct i will be thankful since i have just started with dynamic programming i really am not able to figure it out

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the first point at which it behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified. 
Since you haven't specified your problem, you're not likely to get any specific help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- You seem to use non-local variables for your `for` loops. This is bad practice and can lead to errors that are difficult to debug. Instead 
  do `for (int i = 1;` ...etc.
- `dp[i][i] = 1;` is not part of the `for` loop. You would have detected this if you would have defined `i` only as a variable local to the `for` loop.
  It is good practice to always use braces for the body of a `for` loop (also `if`, `else`, ...etc), even if you would only have one 
  statement in the body.
- `dp[i][i] = 1;` is also a bad assignment: it just is not true that `integerPartition(i, i)` always returns 1. It happens to be true
  for small values of `i`, but not when `i` is greater than 3. For instance, `integerPartition(4, 4)` should return 5.
  Just remove this line.
- In the final nested `for` loop you are mixing up the row/column in your `dp` array. Note that you had reserved the first dimension for `n` and the second dimension for `m`, so opposite to the parameter order.
  That is fine, but you do not stick to that decision in this `for` loop. Instead of `dp[i][j-1]` you should have written `dp[i-1][j]`, and instead of `dp[i-j][j]` you should have
  written `dp[i][j-i]`. And so the `if` condition should be adapted accordingly.
- There is no `return` statement in your version, but maybe you just forgot to include it in the question. It should be
  `return dp[n][m];`

Here is the corrected code:

```
long long int dp[n+1][m+1];

for(int i = 0; i <=n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
        dp[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    dp[i][0] = 1;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for (int j = 1; j <= m ; j++) {
        dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
        if (j >= i) {
            dp[i][j] += dp[i][j-i];
        }
    }
}

return dp[n][m];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and yeah i agree i messed up in that decisions for assignments and i was having a hard time to find out my error can you suggest me what is the approach i should follow to convert any recursive function like this into a dp based approach

Comment: I don't think there is a general method to convert any recursive method to a DP based approach. Some recursive algorithms cannot even be turned in to DP, because the base case is not known at the start, only when the recursion brings information down the recursion tree. For instance a depth-first search in a graph will mark nodes as visited, and the base case is when a node has no unvisited neighbors. You don't know those nodes beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this *technically* is DP, but if your goal is to get the benefits of DP, *memorization* might be a better approach.

The idea is made up of 2 parts:

1. At the start of each call to `integerPartition`, look up in a table (your `dp` will do nicely) to see if that computation has already been done, and if it has, just return the value stored in the table.
2. Just before any point where `integerPartition` is to return a value, store it in the table.

Note that this means you don't need to try to "pivot" the original code -- it proceeds as it did originally, so you are almost guaranteed to get the same results, but without as much unnecessary re-computation (at the code of extra storage).

Comment: Thanks @Scott Hunter but can u check out my cpp code and tell me where am i wrong i am not getting it if possible

Answer (score 0):

so, basis of your code comment, 
I am going to assume  you only want 1 when n > 0 and m = 0 according to your recursive code, but in dp code, you interchanged them, that is i go to upto n, and j go upto m
so updating your code, try to find the mistake

```
        // n -> no. of persons
        // m -> amount of money to be distributed
        // dp table of order (n+1)*(m+1) 
        long long int dp[n+1][m+1] ;
        //initializing values to 0
        for(i = 0; i<=n ; i++)
            for(j = 0; j<= m ; j++)
                dp[i][j] = 0;

        Print(n,m,dp);
        cout << "\n";
        //Case 1 - if there is no persons i.e n = 0 answer will be 0
        //Case 2 - if there is no money i.e. m = 0 there is only 1 way answer will be 1

        for ( i = 1; i<= n; i++){
            dp[i][0] = 0;
        }

        for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++){
            dp[0][j] = 1;
        }

        Print(n,m,dp);

        for ( i = 1; i<= n ; i++){
            for ( j = 1; j<= m ; j++){
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] ;

                if(i>=j){
                    dp[i][j] += dp[i-j][j];
                }
                // else if(i==j){
                //     dp[i][j] += 1;
                // }
            }
    }
```